# vpython in ubuntu/fedora16 : failed to initialize any OpenGL

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, vpython

I have a `Ubuntu 10.10`

when I try use visual with python I get

```
>>> from visual import *
>>> sphere()
VPython ***CRITICAL ERROR***: /build/buildd/python-visual-5.12/./src/gtk2/render_surface.cpp:88: render_surface: failed to initialize any OpenGL configuration, Aborting.
```

Note: this happens in Fedora 16 as well:

```
; env VPYTHON_DEBUG=1 ipython test.py
VPython: ./python/cvisualmodule.cpp:144: Importing cvisual from vpython-core2.
VPython: ./gtk2/display.cpp:66: Opening a window from Python.
VPython: ./gtk2/display.cpp:474: Starting GUI thread.
VPython: ./gtk2/display.cpp:491: Adding new display object at address 0x25168a0
VPython ***CRITICAL ERROR***: ./gtk2/render_surface.cpp:88: render_surface: failed to initialize any OpenGL configuration, Aborting.
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a library conflict between MESA and NVidia libGL libraries as [described in this email thread](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=20120601092840.GA10737@isotek.co.uk&forum_name=visualpython-users).  Just moving `/usr/lib/libGL.so` away (take a backup), running `ldconfig`, and fixing the broken `/usr/lib/libGL.so` link should solve your problem.